# Conditional extraction of rows from 2D NUMPY array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array my_data and I want to extract row **i** if the 4th column of row i has a 0 && the 4th column of row **i-i** has a 1.

I do this now using list comprehension but is there a "non-list" faster way to do this?

'''

my_data = array([(65535, 255, 0, 1, 1), (65535, 255, 0, 1, 1),
(65535, 255, 0, 1, 1), ..., (65535, 255, 0, 1, 1),
(65535, 255, 0, 1, 1), (65535, 255, 0, 1, 1)],
dtype=[('col_0', '<u2'), ('col_1', 'u1'), ('col_2', 'u1'), ('col_3', 'u1'), ('col_4', 'u1')])

filtered_data = [my_data[i] for i in range(1,len(my_data)) if (my_data[i][4] == 0 and my_data[i-1][4] == 1)]

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your array is **structured**, with named columns,
so you can make some use of these features.

As a source array I used:

```
my_data = np.array([
    (65535, 240, 0, 1, 1),
    (65535, 241, 0, 1, 0),
    (65535, 242, 0, 1, 1),
    (65535, 243, 0, 1, 0),
    (65535, 244, 0, 1, 1),
    (65535, 245, 0, 1, 1)],
    dtype=[('col_0', '<u2'), ('col_1', 'u1'), ('col_2', 'u1'),
           ('col_3', 'u1'),  ('col_4', 'u1')])
```

The first step is to take the 4-th column and the same column again,
but shifted by 1 position to the right, inserting *0* as the initial
element:

```
c4 = my_data['col_4']
c4prev = np.insert(c4[:-1], 0, 0)
```

Both these arrays contain:

```
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

And to get the expected result use boolean indexing:

```
result = my_data[np.logical_and(c4 == 0, c4prev == 1)]
```

The result is:

```
array([(65535, 241, 0, 1, 0), (65535, 243, 0, 1, 0)],
      dtype=[('col_0', '<u2'), ('col_1', 'u1'), ('col_2', 'u1'),
             ('col_3', 'u1'), ('col_4', 'u1')])
```

so just the intended rows have been extracted.